# Why do textareas break long words (and why don't divs break long words) when it exceeds the width?

Tags: html, css, overflow, word-wrap

Let's say I have two boxes: `div.box` and `textarea.box`, each of which has the same fixed width and height. Each also has identical text including one verrryyyyy long word, followed by a series of short words.

The setup might look like this:

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong_word and short text
</div>

<br><br>

<textarea class="box">
looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong_word and short text
</textarea>
```

Using the above code, the `div` does not break the long word, then begins on the next line with the series of short words:

[image: div.box image]

However, the `textarea` breaks the long word:

[image: textarea.box image]

My question: Why does this happen? What default CSS is causing the `div` to keep the long word on one line (i.e. not break the word), but the `textarea` to break it?

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QZDe6/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome default textarea styling:

```
textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-image: initial;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    resize: auto;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The `word-wrap: break-word;` is the cause.

The `overflow` property can only hide the overflowing content or allow it to be scrolled. Use `word-wrap: break-word;` to allow long words to be broken.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in the default value of the [`word-wrap` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap) of each element.

By default the browser's native stylesheet applies `word-wrap:normal` to the `div` element, whereas to the `textarea` element it applies `word-wrap:break-word`.

In other words, for `div` elements the browser assumes that if the text overflows the specified dimensions, whole words cannot be broken to fit the container, while for `textarea` elements it assumes that word breaking is acceptable. This difference becomes very apparent when (as in this case) the overflow is not suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's not what overflow does, you may be want to take a look at the word-wrap property (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap).

You want to apply word-wrap: break-word; to the element.